# In Oracle, when inserting a large number of rows, Is dropping and recreating indexes faster?

Tags: oracle, indexing, insert

I have an indexed table to which I have to add about 150000 records daily. This takes a lot of time using insert statements. Is it faster to

*first drop the index
then insert the records
then create the index again*

Comment: When you say “using insert statements”, how many insert statements are you running? Where is the data coming from? How fast is fast enough? Dropping indexes can help bulk inserts but the recreation usually takes even longer and you won’t be able to use the indexes for a period

Comment: How many indexes?  Compressed?  Have you tried the `/*+ append */` hint?

Comment: Have you considered PARTITION the table and using a local index if that fits your needs

Comment: @Mark if you're suggesting append perhaps use this INSERT /*+ PARALLEL(16) APPEND */ ....

Comment: The only real way to know is to try it. That being said, my experience leads me to believe that you'll get better overall performance by dropping all indexes, inserting your data, and recreating the indexes.